# Easiest way to include audio into website

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

Im looking to include some audio into a webpage which will be automatically played on command when some action is done. What is the easiest way to do this without having any physical play/pause buttons on the screen. If so, it it possible to do this just through javascript?

(I'm a beginner so please explain a little more in detail if you can!)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: There has to be event [ like onLoad, onClick,....] to perform some action [ like  play/pause ]

Answer (score 0):

Just add an audio tag in your html.. and link to where your audio file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio style="display:none"  autoplay="autoplay" >
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">

Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

use either mp3 or ogg files.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Comment: `<audio controls autoplay>` autoplay to play automatically on load

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the [HTML 5 `audio` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

Omit the `controls` attribute to remove the *physical play/pause*. And add `autoplay` to make the sound play once it's loaded

Answer (score 0):

use html5 `audio` tag, with `autoplay` attribute, like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/grassog/odL69p59/

Comment: Thanks! But i have one question. This is autoplayed right when the webpage is loaded up. How do i make it so that when i certain value is met this audio will be played. i.e. when plays the audio when the user does a certain action.

Comment: you use javascript, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/grassog/dLza0n1z/

Answer (score 0):

Use audio tag

```
 <audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Play audio
</audio>
```